# Excel user form using unique values and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with one thing in a User form. I have a dropdown where the data is taking from a sheet. I want only unique values in the droplist. I already have the code, how can I edit this code to give only unique values in the droplist?

Note: the Dropdown button name is `cmbSelChartAttr` and datas for this dropdown is taken from "Inconsistency Order" Sheet.

```vb
Function formInitialize(ws As Worksheet)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inconsistency Order")

    If ws.Visible = True Then
        ws.Activate
    Else
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ws.Activate
    End If

    Dim i, lc
    Dim j
    Dim tecAttrVal As String

    lc = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    i = 0

    For i = i + 1 To lc

        tecAttrVal = Cells(1, i).Value
        Me.cmbSelChartAttr.AddItem tecAttrVal
        tecAttrVal = ""
        Me.Label3.Visible = False
        Me.lsbOrderSet4SelAttr.Visible = False

    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Note that `For i = i + 1 To lc` is a strange syntax and should be `For i = 1 To lc` (and `i = 0` is not needed). It increments `i` by `1` at `Next i` automatically. Also define the proper type for all of your variables `Dim i As Long, lc As Long`. • Specify the sheet for `tecAttrVal = Cells(1, i).Value` like `tecAttrVal = ws.Cells(1, i).Value` or Excel starts guessing.

Comment: Also there is no need to use `If ws.Visible = True Then ..... Else ...End If ` branch. Only `ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible` and `ws.Activate` would suffice